# How to pass jQuery variables to PHP variable?

Tags: php, jquery, variables

How do you pass a variable from jQuery to PHP without a page refresh? When I click on a checkbox I would like to pass a variable from jQuery to PHP. I am also using formdialog.

My PHP code

```
<?php
echo "<input name='opendialog' type='checkbox' class='opendialog' onclick='countChecked()' value=".$taskid." ?>" /> </td>"
?>
```

my javascript code

```
function countChecked() {
  var n = $("input:checked").length;

  var allVals = [];
   $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
   allVals.push($(this).val());

   });
   $('.sel').text(allVals+' ');
   $('.select1').val(allVals);
   alert(allVals);

    <?php $taskidj=$rowtask['taskID'];
   // echo "aaa...".$rowtask['taskID']; ?>     

}

$(":checkbox").click(countChecked);


// my jquery code


        $('.mydialog').dialog({

            bgiframe: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 700,
            height:500,
            resizable: false,
            open: function(){closedialog = 1;$(document).bind('click', overlayclickclose);},
            focus: function(){closedialog = 0;},
            close: function(){$(document).unbind('click');},
            buttons: {
                Submit: function(){
                var bValid = true;
            //  allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

            //  bValid = bValid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );



            //  bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );





                if ( bValid ) {

                        processDetails();

                        return false;

                }


                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    $('input[name=opendialog]').attr('checked', false);
                }
            }
        });

    $('.opendialog').click(function() {
            $('.mydialog').dialog('open');
            closedialog = 0;
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variable from JavaScript to PHP using jQuery POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376913/how-to-pass-variable-from-javascript-to-php-using-jquery-post)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ajax can do this.  Google it, and check out [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com) and look at the ajax functions, .ajax(), .post(), .get(), .load(), etc.

As for your specific question, here is what you would do:

```
//Javascript file
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
   $.post('my_ajax_receiver.php', 'val=' + $(this).val(), function (response) {
      alert(response);
   });
});

//PHP file my_ajax_receiver.php
<?php
   $value = $_POST['val'];
   echo "I got your value! $value";
?>
```

Comment: hi tandu,  Undefined index: val. i use the code isset() function.but i cann't receive the value.

Comment: Check what $(this).val() is.  Are you defining a value for your checkbox?