# How can i check if the radio button is checked or not without a submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

How can i check the value of the radio box whether its Pearson or euclidean.
So what i have now is this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    {

        if($_POST['radio'] == 'Euclidean'){
        $get_recommendations = get_recommendations($new_videos,$user_data['username'], $sim_score='sim_euclidean');
        }

    }
    // as default i want the pearson method to be used
    else{
        $get_recommendations = get_recommendations($new_videos,$user_data['username'], $sim_score='sim_pearson');
```

Do i have to have a button to subit the value chosen, or is there a way to get the value without having a submit button?

This is the form i have:

```
          <form action="" method="post"> 
          <div class="control-group">
            <h1 style="font-size:22px;">Choose method to recommend with:</h1>
            <label class="control control--radio">Pearson
              <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Pearson" checked="checked"/>
              <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <label class="control control--radio">Euclidean
              <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Euclidean"/>
              <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
          </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: You'll need javascript or jquery

Comment: @clearshot66 How would the JavaScript look like tho, could you help me out with that?

Comment: I'll submit an answer with jquery quick. Gimme a second

Comment: @clearshot66 cheers

Answer (score 1):

With jquery, give radio a class or id of radio for example:

```
$(document).ready(function()){

$('input:radio[name="radio"]').change(function()){
var value = $('form input[type=radio]:checked').val();  // Gets val of checked on change event

// code to manipulate it, can also be sent to a php file via ajax if you need it that way
}

}
```

Link for passing variables around jquery to php
[Passing jQuery Value to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205151/passing-jquery-value-to-php)

Comment: Is it possible to check if that value is equal to something within the php? Or should it also include ajax like u added?

Comment: If it's a php variable you'd have to ajax it to php, since JS is front end and PHP is back end

Comment: No i mean the value that i retrieved from jquery. How can i use it in php? Should it be using ajax?

Comment: As I just said, if you're trying to compare the javascriptvalue AGAINST a php variable, you'd have to ajax the javascript variable to php, to compare AGAINST the php variable you want. What exactly are you trying to do? I may be able to help you write it differently so it doesn't need to be done that way.

Comment: What i really want is to check if the value is equal to Pearson or Euclidean so i can Make a recommendation towards the specified name. How would the code you helped me with be useful in that case?

Comment: You could do that front end, just check whether the radio button == 'Pearson' or 'Euclidean', then output text via JavaScript by appending it to a div or displaying one div or another based on that decision. If you need anything database related you can get that via ajax

Comment: It's super easy to do what I said, like maybeeeee 10 lines. But okay :)

Comment: Yeah i have no idea how to use js thats why im backing off lol

Comment: To be a good programmer you need to want to constantly learn, and JavaScript Jquery aren't going away :)

Comment: I mean i could easily do this if didnt have a bad headache and im feeling so dizzy lol. I do appreciate the motivation tho lol