# jquery id element inside php variable

Tags: php, jquery

I would to store inside a php variable the ID of the checkbox that has been selected.

Something like this, but this isn't working.

```
<?php $myvar='$(".chkspec:checkbox").attr("id")';?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass jquery variables to php variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202070/how-to-pass-jquery-variables-to-php-variable)

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the value somehow with AJAX.

PHP server side code has no access to client side information (and the same vis versa)

Comment: Thanks, can you make an example with AJAX, because the ID of the checkbox should be passed to another PHP page.

Comment: No. No I cannot @user2588490. Read up on AJAX on the internet -- there are examples all over. Including on this site...

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language, that is it is interpreted in the server alone...
On the other side Javascript is a client side language, tha means it runs on the users computer (usually its browser).

What you are trying to do does not work because of the fact that the codes are interpreted in different places.

Maybe AJAX would do the trick. So you should check it out.

Answer (score 0):

What you're currently doing wouldn't work. Because:

- PHP won't be able to access the webpage's information after it's rendered in the browser
- The checkbox ID is to be retrieved dynamically. Storing a value in a variable is not going to work, at least for the goal you're trying to achieve.

The solution would be to use AJAX. You can pass the your ID element using as follows:

**Example:**

```
$.ajax({
  url:'somefile.php',
  type:'GET',
  data: {id:yourVariable},
  success:function(res){
    // code
  }
});
```

And in your PHP file, you can access the variable like so:

```
$myvar = $_GET['id'];
```

Hope this helps!