# Undefined index error when sending variable from jquery to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Adapted from this question: [Passing Jquery variable to php within a modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881307/passing-jquery-variable-to-php-within-a-modal)

I have it set up, and it should be working, but I am getting the undefined index error.

Inside a while loop:

```
print '<li>';
        print '<a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-id='.$row['id'].' data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"><img src="'.$row["image"].'" /></a><br>';
        print '<a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-id='.$row['id'].' data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"><h4>'.$row['name'].'</h4></a>';
print '</li>';
```

All of my jquery, including the ajax code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("body").css("display", "none");
            $("body").fadeIn(1000);
            $("a.transition").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                linkLocation = this.href;
                $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
            });
            function redirectPage() {
                window.location = linkLocation;
            }
        }); 
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert (id);
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            alert (id);
            $("h4.modal-title").text(id);

            //$($(this).attr('href')).modal('show');    
            $.post('food.php',{id:id},function(data){
                alert(data);
                alert (id) // <--THIS ALERT WORKS TOO
            });
        });
```

The php:

```
<?php
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        print '<h4>'.$id.'</h4>'

    ?>
```

I keep getting an index undefined error on `$id = $_POST["id"];`.

I cant seem to figure out why, I have adapted my code to so many different ways of doing it, but none of them work.

The first alert shows up, but the second does not. The text does get placed within the `<div>`, however it does not get sent to the variable. All of this is in one file.
I have a feeling my ajax code is missing something.

A Var dump shows:

```
array (size=0)
   empty
```

Comment: i did't see href attribute in your a tag.

Comment: Ah, I can comment that code out, it still gives the error

Comment: weird, can you try replace `var id = $(this).data('id');` into `var id = $(this).attr('data-id');`.

Comment: Shouldn't the first `id` should be in quotes that is sending to the PHP page I think otherwise it is the variable. `{'id'` or look at the data be transmitted is it as expected?

Comment: @chris85 I don't think that makes a difference

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali I tried it.. still gives the error

Comment: @chris85, I thought so too, but I removed my answer.   I would guess you can't use variables in the key since it automatically evaluates that as a string.

Comment: @Devon You'd have to use square bracket notation for that `obj[id] = id`, otherwise yeah, it doesn't take the variable's value into account.

Comment: What if you try sending the data as `{id: 'test'}` just to test it out? And check the parameters being sent in the network tab.

Comment: still returns an error, how do i get to the network tab? im a noob... still learning

Comment: I am sending this to a modal, if it makes a difference, and also all of this is on the same page.. not replicating server side or anything.. all I want to do is transfer the clicked id to the modal so I can run a query on it

Comment: To check the network tab, open up the developer's console by pressing `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `i` or `F12` and then click on `Network`. Trigger the POST request and it should be logged in there. Click on it. If you are in Chrome, then click on the `Headers` tab and scroll to the bottom, you should see something that says parameters or the like. If you are in Firefox, there's a nice tab that says `Params`, click on that.

Comment: Under form data, i see it: `id:test`, I tried it with the actual variable and I got:  1 (which is expected).

Comment: Hmm, so it is being sent. Do you see any further redirects? I think that maybe your server is redirecting the POST, and the request ends up in a GET request. Do a `var_dump` of `$_GET` as the first line in your code and see what you get.

Comment: A var dump as `GET` returns the same result as a var dump of `POST`,  which is basically an array `(size=0) empty`, this is so frustrating.. been at it for 3 days

Comment: Aaaah... What if you add a '/' at the end of the URL to your file? As in `'food.php/'`, also, try with the absolute path: `'/some_location/food.php'` and `'/some_location/food.php/'` (but using `$_POST`, of course)

Comment: Still gives the error.. zzz

Comment: Geez... I've ran out of ideas then, haha. So, the parameters are being sent, I think that then there's something fishy going on in your PHP file (you didn't post the full PHP code, did you?). You could also try using the `$.ajax` method, although I'm not sure that'd make much of a difference.

Comment: In my whole code.. theres only 2 php sections..  one which prints out the information (the while loop) and the second section is basically to take in the variable from jquery.. and yeah i tried the ajax method too

Comment: Is there another way of doing this whole thing?

Comment: @user2883071 check out the answer on your other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881307/passing-jquery-variable-to-php-within-a-modal , it will walk you through the whole process with a working example

Answer (score 0):

Use the following php code and try again

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST["id"] ) ) 
        $id = $_POST["id"];
    else
        $id = 'Error: id not exist';
    print '<h4>'.$id.'</h4>';
    die();
?>
```

Comment: It says Error: id not exist

Comment: I didn't get your code:  var id = $(this).data('id'); what do you want from this code ?

Comment: So when someone clicks either the image or the name, the id is transferred to the jquery variable id. ( think thats what it means)

Answer (score 0):

you are already assuming data is posted. 
try if isset

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
     $id = $_POST["id"];
  echo $id;
    }
```

Comment: This also does not return anything

Comment: It does not return anything because no data is getting passed. check this line of code  var id = $(this).data('id');  instead try adding var id = $(this).data('data-id');

Comment: Makes no difference either